# How can I disable right-click or left-click with terminal(bash)

Tags: bash, scripts, mouse

I want to write a bash script that when for example `vncviewer` is running, my right-click would be disabled 
So first, how can I check that if a program is running or not with bash script ??
and second, how can I disable the right-click when this program is running ??

Comment: Will probably depend on whether you use synaptics or libinput as driver. Once you know, you probably can programatically change settings ("properties").

Comment: I'm not using touchpad and also want to do these with terminal(I want to use the commands in bash scripts

Comment: http://xmodulo.com/create-desktop-shortcut-launcher-linux.html 2nd answer with xinput may help.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/513697/how-to-disable-right-click-only-on-desktop-and-icons-in-xfce4 another example where right-click is disabled using xmodmap